# Mysql serivce can't start it, with the control process exited with error code problem

Tags: mysql

my os is Redhat8.
currtenly I install Mysql, version is "mysql  Ver 8.0.13 for Linux on x86_64 (Source distribution)"

I use command "sudo yum install mysql, mysql-server"

But i get error when i want to start mysql services. I keep finding soluction, but still I don't know how to solved it.

Can anyone help me to look at it?

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[yliu@rhlab1 ~]$ sudo systemctl start mysqld
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
[yliu@rhlab1 ~]$ sudo systemctl status mysqld
● mysqld.service - MySQL 8.0 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-02-19 12:12:15 AST; 15s ago
  Process: 13080 ExecStopPost=/usr/libexec/mysql-wait-stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 13052 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 13015 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-prepare-db-dir mysqld.service (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 12991 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-check-socket (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 13052 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "SERVER_BOOTING"
    Error: 2 (No such file or directory)

Feb 19 12:12:12  systemd[1]: Starting MySQL 8.0 database server...
Feb 19 12:12:15  systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 19 12:12:15  systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 19 12:12:15  systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL 8.0 database server.

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
[yliu@rhlab1 ~]$ sudo cat /var/log/mysql/mysqld.log | nl | tail -n 10
    38  2020-02-19T15:48:25.492390Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)  Source distribution.
    39  2020-02-19T15:48:25.492468Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010065] [Server] Failed to shutdown components infrastructure.
    40  2020-02-19T16:12:13.332724Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 13052
    41  2020-02-19T16:12:13.585641Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010781] [Server] Found ./mysql/index_stats.frm file in mysql schema. DD will create .ibd file with same name. Please rename table and start upgrade process again.
    42  2020-02-19T16:12:13.585666Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010336] [Server] Found .frm file with same name as one of the Dictionary Tables.
    43  2020-02-19T16:12:13.585833Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
    44  2020-02-19T16:12:13.585871Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] Newly created data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can safely remove it.
    45  2020-02-19T16:12:13.585881Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
    46  2020-02-19T16:12:15.000469Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)  Source distribution.
    47  2020-02-19T16:12:15.000550Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010065] [Server] Failed to shutdown components infrastructure.
```

My /etc/my.cnf.d/mysql-server.cnf information is:

```
[yliu@rhlab1 ~]$ sudo cat /etc/my.cnf.d/mysql-server.cnf
#
# This group are read by MySQL server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
#
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mysqld according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log
pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: This question is more for the superuser forum. Kindly resubmit : https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem, hope it will helpful for everyone who meet the same problem.

Base on the log:

```
    41  2020-02-19T16:12:13.585641Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010781] [Server] Found ./mysql/index_stats.frm file in mysql schema. DD will create .ibd file with same name. Please rename table and start upgrade process again.
    42  2020-02-19T16:12:13.585666Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010336] [Server] Found .frm file with same name as one of the Dictionary Tables.
    43  2020-02-19T16:12:13.585833Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
    44  2020-02-19T16:12:13.585871Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] Newly created data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can safely remove it.
```

so we can remove all the files under /var/lib/mysql/
and then make sure the mysql file owner and group are mysql.

```
(Django) [yliu@rhlab1 ops]$ sudo ls -al /var/lib/ | grep mysql
drwxr-xr-x.  7 mysql          mysql          4096 Feb 24 10:16 mysql
```

and then you can start mysqld again

```
sudo systemctl start mysqld
```

Comment: This worked like a charm on rocky linux 8. Thank you